# Comparison of Blurring techniques used in Computer Vision

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

Recently while studying Computer Vision using the OpenCV library, I came across blurring/smoothing techniques used to remove noise from an image. I understand each technique has its pros and cons. However I could not get a clear understanding as too which technique is the best and should be used at all times. I'd like to have a feedback from you guys, as I am a beginner.

Comment: Visit [THIS PAGE](http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_filtering/py_filtering.html#filtering)

Comment: You can also look at http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/34126/random-noise-removal-in-images/34149#34149 for more advance methods

Comment: For most basic applications, a gaussian blur is a good way to start.

Comment: "should be used at all times" - as you said, each one has its own pros and cons and typically none completely dominates another. So you should collect some experience to decide which one to use for a specific task. Often, people design some kind of framework where each method can be embedded => simple way to change a specific method for testing.

Comment: Use this for the link submitted by Jeru Luke: https://web.archive.org/web/20170430231358/https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_filtering/py_filtering.html